# Submit a form made of multiple components

Tags: javascript, forms, events, components, angular

I've started Angular2 lately and I am facing a problem. I want to create a form to generate some multiple choices questions and this is my problem :

I have a FormComponent which display the layout of my form.
The AnswerComponent can be added to the FormComponent to provide multiple choices about the question.
I have been using the DynamicComponentLoader to programatically add thoses AnswerComponent inside of my FormComponent.

The thing is the submit button must belong to the FormComponent and I do not know how to alert my AnswerComponent to send their data to the FormComponent so it cans gather all the data and create my question.

If anyone has an idea that would be great !

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a sample. I have a form that manages company details:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="companyForm">
  <field label="Name" [state]="companyForm.controls.name">
    <input [ngFormControl]="companyForm.controls.name" [(ngModel)]="company.name"/> {{name.valid}}
  </field>
  <field label="Tags">
    <tags [(labels)]="company.labels"></tags>
  </field>

  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!companyForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

As you can see, I use two sub components:

- The `field` one that aims to build the layout for a field block using Bootstrap3. It accepts a variable area to provide the form element (input, select, textarea). This component also leverages the associated control to display validation errors if any.
- The `tags` one that manages the `tags` attribute that is a list of string. It allows to display, add and remove tags.

You can see that every form element leverages two way binding. This means that each form element is associated to a property of an object of the component. Here it's the `company` one that is a property of the component.

This means that when you want to submit the form, you can use this `company` object to build the payload of the corresponding HTTP request for example.

Let's deal a bit more with the associated with the `company` object. For inputs, it's obvious using the ngModel directive with this syntax: `[(ngModel)]`. With the `tags` sub component, it's perhaps not so obvious.

In fact you need define inputs and outputs to manage the `labels` with two ways bindings:

```
@Input labels:string[]
@Output labelsChanged: EventEmitter
```

When labels are updated, you need to call the `emit` method of `labelsChanged`.

Here is the complete code for the `TagsComponent` component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tags',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="labels">
      <span *ngFor="#label of labels" style="font-size:14px"
          class="label label-default" (click)="removeLabel(label)">
        {{label}} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </span>
      <span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
      <span style="display:inline-block;">
        <input [(ngModel)]="labelToAdd" style="width: 50px; font-size: 14px;" class="custom"/>
        <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" (click)="addLabel(labelToAdd)"></em>
      </span>
    </div>
  `
})
export class TagsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  labels:string[];
  @Output()
  labelsChange: EventEmitter;

  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {
    this.labelsChange = new EventEmitter();
  }

  removeLabel(label:string) {
    var index = this.labels.indexOf(label, 0);
    if (index != undefined) {
       this.labels.splice(index, 1);
       this.labelsChange.emit(this.labels);
    }
  }

  addLabel(label:string) {
    this.labels.push(this.labelToAdd);
    this.labelsChange.emit(this.labels);
    this.labelToAdd = '';
  }
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: In your TagsComponent, how does Angular to know that Input labels and Output labelsChange is a two way binding and not just an in and an out separate like this : 
<tags [labels]="company.labels" (labelsChange)="company.labels"></tags>?

Comment: In fact, by convertion, if you have an input named `something` and an output `somethingChanged`, you can use the syntax `[(something)]` to leverage two way binding for this element ;-)